# Reading in .txt file with different extension in C

Tags: c, file, text

At the moment my program has no problem reading in a .txt file, but my program needs to read in a text file with a different file extension (.emu is the requirement). When simply changing the same file's extension to .emu, the variable 'file' is NULL and therefore the file isn't opened, can anyone help?

Had a little look around and haven't been able to find a solution so any help is much appreciated

here's the source code:

```
void handleArgs (const char *filename, int trace, int before, int after) {
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
char *address = malloc(MAX_ADD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
char *instruction = malloc(MAX_INS_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
long int addressDecoded;

if (file == NULL || file == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open file");
}
else {
    if (ferror(file) == 0) {
        while (fscanf(file, "%s %s", address, instruction) != EOF) {
            if (strlen(address) == 8 && strlen(instruction) == 8) {
                addressDecoded = strtol(address, NULL, 16);
                printf("%ld\n", addressDecoded);
                //instruction = decodeInstruction(instruction);
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: particular line is of wrong length");
            }

        }
    }
}

fclose(file);
```

}

argument 'filename' when executing is simply '/foopath/test.emu'

Comment: Can you post the source code that opens your file handle?

Comment: Can you post some code? Is the file there when you try to open it? Extensions have no impact on `fopen`, so there must be something else going on

Comment: Your problem is not the extension.

Comment: Can we see some code? If you hardcoded the filename into the code, you'd have to update the extension.

Comment: Can you post the output of "`ls -al /foopath/test*`"? (I'm assuming you're running some form of Unix since the example path you gave suggests that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special to C about the file extension.  Reread your code for simple errors like changing the filename in one place, but not the other.  If you're passing in the filename, pass the whole name, not just the part to the left of the period.

Comment: Also - make sure the new file is in the current working directly, that it's not set read-only and you're trying to open in write mode, user context has access to the file, make sure another program doesn't have that file open at the same time (in Windows, anyway), etc, etc, etc.

Comment: fixed, OSX was hiding the fact that when i renamed the file to 'test.emu', it was actually just 'test.emu.txt'

Comment: @Will, I see.  I always disable that "feature" when I encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

Files are data, and have names. What comes before the dot in a name, is just as much a part of it as what comes after -- the **extensions were created just as hints** as to what the file contains, but **they are NOT required to be strictly related to the file's contents**.

The file may not exist, or your priviledges may not be enough to open it. Or maybe there's some other kind of error. How can you diagnose this?

When you use a system call and it doesn't behave the way you want to, there's a variable called `errno` in `errno.h` (`#include <errno.h>`) that will contain a number representing the status of the last call. There's a huge list of symbolic constants to put names to these values, you can google it up.

For example, if you try to open a file and the returned pointer is useless, you might want to check `errno` to see if the file existed, or if you're exceding system restrictions for opened files, etc.